# JSF2 using JSP2.0 - custom components issue

Tags: java, jsf-2

We are migrating JSF1.2 to JSF2.0 using JSP2.
JSF 2.0 with JSP2 on RAD 8 is the exact specification we are lookig for.
We are getting some issues on custom tags and component classes. how can i configure component classes and custom tags in JSP( by using TLD file or *.taglib.xml)
note: not for JSTL tags
on this combination, no concrete solutions were available even from the internet and from other sources.

Requesting leads and expertise to resolve this.

Thanks
Prabhakar Reddy

Answer (score 0):

JSP was deprecated in JSF 2, so if you want to do the migration, the best path is move your old JSP pages to JSF 2 Facelets VDL. Then it depends on what you have in your code. See: [Migration from JSF 1.2 to 2.0/2.1](http://myfaces.apache.org/wiki/core/user-guide/migration-guide/from-1.2-to-2.0---2.1.html)

Comment: yes it is the right way what you said but its need more efforts, so we decided to go with JSF2.0 using JSPs.

Comment: The new features in JSF 2.0 like built-in ajax, composite components, Partial State Saving and so on are in Facelets only, not in JSP.

Comment: Is there any way to write custom tags using components and renderers in JSF2.0 using JSP?

Comment: You have to write them using JSF 1.2 style. It will work in 2.0.